# Enable HTTP2 support for JBoss

Tags: java, jsf, jboss

Shifting to HTTP2 was not very hard in Nginx.
Don't know how I can do this with JBoss though.

So my questions are:

1. Does JBoss support HTTP2 ?
2. If yes how do I enable support for it ?
3. If no when will support for it be available ?

Currently my application is running on JBoss with JSF as the framework of choice.

Comment: see here if it helps http://blog.eisele.net/2015/11/http2-with-jboss-eap-7.html

Comment: Are there any more links ? @gladiator

Comment: I have a paid subscription of red hat and they provide me this link for configuration see if it helps you .
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuration_guide/configuring_the_web_server_undertow

check this section 17.11. CONFIGURING HTTP/2

Comment: @gladiator how about integrating Lets Ecnrypt with JBoss ?